# ¿Se puede mostrar una aplicación Java en un documento HTML?

Tags: java, html5

Me gustaria saber si se puede y que necesito saber para hacerlo en el caso de que se pueda.

Comment: Por favor especifica a que te refieres con una "aplicación Java" o que es lo que pretendes, por ejemplo si deseas pasar una aplicación de escritorio, un sitio hecho con Java ( JSP, JSF, Servlets, etc ). O si te refieres a una aplicación web hecha con Java simplemente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualmente no, antes si se permitía mediante Applets , pero por problemas de seguridad se desaconsejó su uso hasta prohíbirlo por completo, puedes ejecutar applets en navegadores antiguos como internet explorer, pero supongo que no es lo que buscas.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet_Java#Desventajas

> Los applets de Java tienen las siguientes desventajas:
>
> 1. Requiere el plugin de Java, sin embargo los navegadores Chrome y Edge no soportan plugins y Firefox dejará de soportarlos
>      próximamente.En ese sentido también Oracle anunció que abandonará el
>      desarrollo del plugin de Java a partir de la salida de Java 9.1
> 2. No puede iniciar la ejecución hasta que la JVM esté en funcionamiento, y esto puede tomar tiempo la primera vez que se
>      ejecuta un applet.
> 3. Si no está firmado como confiable, tiene un acceso limitado al sistema del usuario - en particular no tiene acceso directo al disco
>      duro del cliente o al portapapeles.
> 4. Algunas organizaciones sólo permiten la instalación de software a los administradores. Como resultado, muchos usuarios (sin privilegios 
>      para instalar el plugin en su navegador) no pueden ver los applets.
> 5. Un applet podría exigir una versión específica del JRE.
> 6. Puede tener vulnerabilidades que permitan ejecutar código malicioso.

Como puedes ver, los navegadores ya no permiten applets porque ya no permiten plugins, lo mismo sucedió con flash hace poco.

Puedes utilizar java para hacer una web para eso existe [JSP (Java server page)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), pero no puedes mostrar una aplicación java en una web, son cosas totalmente distintas

Comment: Que mal, gracias por tu respuesta y por compartir esta información. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Si bien **no** puedes mostrar una aplicación **de escritorio** actualmente en la web como cuando estaban habilitados los Applets, es posible referenciarla mediante [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start), y asegurarte de esta manera que se ejecute la última versión.
Podrás hallar algunos ejemplos en la [página oficial de tutoriales de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/examplesIndex.html).

Si tu intención es más bien orientada a una **aplicación hecha con Java** con funcionalidad orientada del lado cliente que pueddas usar desde el navegador te recomendaría usar [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript).
Podrás halalr ejemplos en el [editor web online de Dukescript](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#7151306). Dukescript podría serte de utilidad si deseas manejar gráficos en un canvas pues incluso tiene un API para ello, con lo que podrías incluso trabajar con gráficos 3D.

Por otro lado existen muchas tecnologías de Java para el desarrollo de aplicaciones web orientadas para su uso con un funcionalidad en un **servidor basado en Java**, como son [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), [play-framework](/questions/tagged/play-framework), [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf), [vadin](/questions/tagged/vadin), etc.